# ¿Qué quiere decir "engatillado"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, definiciones, modismos

Sé lo que dice el RAE sobre la palabra. Sobre los animales y sobre la chapa.

Pero cuando alguien me dice:

> ¡Chepe, estabas engatillado!

Eso ¿qué quiere decir?

La expresión viene de Colombia.

Comment: Supongo que ayudaría si mencionas de qué parte del mundo de habla hispana has sacado la expresión

Comment: @belisarius Hecho, la expresión viene de COlombia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Engatillar también se refiere a una presa en la cual una de las piezas queda atrapada inmóvil. Estar engatillado quiere decir que te has quedado *atascado*, *atorado*, *atrapado*, *trabado* (no literalmente). 
Una variante con un significado más específico la puedes ver en la siguiente cita:

> Él, un corredor de bolsa con seis años de experiencia encima, afirma
>   que antes de empezar negociaciones más de un operador estaba
>   "engatillado", como se le dice en la jerga bursátil a quien se queda
>   con las ganas de comprar o vender un activo.

Enlace a la frase original:
http://www.elcolombiano.com/BancoConocimiento/N/no_hubo_transaccion_de_acciones_en_bolsa/no_hubo_transaccion_de_acciones_en_bolsa.asp

Answer (score 2):

Es posible que tenga que ver con estar presionado, relacionado al gatillo del arma, o que no se tiene otra opción ante algún problema.
¿Hay algún ejemplo con contexto disponible?